# Python add to Dictionary key, value pair from yaml

Tags: python, python-2.7

How I can parse yaml in cycle to list with format `key: value`. Yaml file:

```
   dbconfig:
     host: localhost
     database: db_test
     username: user
     password: 12345
```

What I do:

```
with open('config.yml', 'r') as yml:
    cfg = yaml.load(yml)
    db_list = {}
    for key, value in cfg['dbconfig']:
        db_list['key'] = value
```

But this do not work.

Comment: No idea if it's the only problem with your code (since you haven't explained how it does not work), but db_list['key'] = value should definitely be db_list[key] = value

Comment: Why iterate the keys at all? `db_list = dict(cfg['dbconfig'])` (if you want a copy), or just `db_list = cfg['dbconfig']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `db_list[key] = value` instead of `'db_list['key'] = value'`.

`db_list[key] = value` will use whatever is in `key` as the dictionary key,
while `db_list['key'] = value'` will use the string `'key'` as the dictionary key.

Have a look at the [the Python docs on dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get a `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.
What you need to do is to iterate over a list of tuples instead of the dictionary. To get the values in the dictionary as key-value tuples use the `items()` method.

```
with open('config.yml', 'r') as yml:
    cfg = yaml.load(yml)
    db_list = {}
    for key, value in cfg['dbconfig'].items():
        db_list[key] = value # you need to use the variable key here
```

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve because in the end, your `db_list` will be the same as `cfg['dbconfig']`.